# Why my test is not running the model observer?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm working in a laravel project where I make some logic while updating data. For this purpose I'm taking advantage of the observer pattern in `updating()` method.

Here are my simplified snippets:

**ModuleObserver**

```php
public function updating($module)
{
    dd('This must be shown');
}
```

**ModuleController**

```php
public function update(ModuleUpdateRequest $request, string $moduleId): ModuleResource
{
  try {
    $module = Module::findOrFail($moduleId);
  } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException('Module not found.');
  }

  $module->fill($request->all());
  $module->save();
}
```

**ModuleControllerTest**

```php
public function testModuleUpdate()
{
  $module = factory(Module::class)->create(['name' => 'My Module']);
  $this->actingAs($this->user)->putJson('/modules/' . $module->id, [ 'name' => 'My Updated Module' ])->assertStatus(200);
}
```

The test passes ok instead of showing the debugger line.

(My observer is correctly loaded in AppServiceProvider file, BTW it works fine out of the test context)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates):

> When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the saving, saved, updating, and updated model events will not be fired for the updated models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update.

To make sure of the model event to be fired you can use model properties ...

Something like:

```
$module->name = $request->input('name');
$module->date = $request->input('date');
// ...........
$module->save();
```